# log4j record-like log

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I want log4j to produce record-like output.

What I DON'T want:

```
1    INFO  ... - User login: Agostino
120  INFO  ... - Start process: 0, elements to process 100
```

What I want:

```
1    INFO ... - User: Agostino, processid:null, elements: null, message: login
1    INFO ... - User: Agostino, processid:0, elements: 100, message: start process
```

I think I should use a ObjectRenderer, and since many data are contained in objects that I already have, so I think something like:

```
public class MyMessage {
    Object myContextObject; //**this** contains user, processid, elements
    String message;
}
```

What I am doing here is passing a "context object" that provides fields PLUS a message string. An ObjectRenderer then will do the formatting, based on myContextObject type.

Now i'm wondering if ObjectRenderer is designed with something like this in mind.
If this was the normal use of ObjectRenderer, probably they'd provide a 
log(String message, Object myContextObject) that prevent the creation of the dummy wrapper MyMessage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative to the `ObjectRenderer`, You might want to look into log4j's `PatternLayout`, which can be configured programmatically, or configuratively:

http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PatternLayout.html

for instance, you can do something like this (just an arbitrary example):

```
<appender name="STDOUT" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
  <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
    <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %-5p (%-35F:%-4L) - %m%n"/>
  </layout>
</appender>
```

Once you've established that, you can use the `%X{clientNumber}` pattern for retrieving data from your custom classes via MDC

http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/MDC.html

Comment: Ok, thanks, I checked the MDC and the %X conversion pattern. The concern with this is passing the key-values from my object to the MDC. Moreover, if I have many objects that live in the same thread, because the MDC context is thread based.

Comment: I re-state my initial question pheraps too verbose. Simply speaking: i want to render to the log an object (that represents my context) *and* a message.

Comment: You can have several `%X{context} %X{message}` pattern elements... We do that in our app. At the beginning of every `ServletRequest`, we initialise MDC with all relevant information. Since a `ServletRequest` "owns" the thread for the lifespan of the request, this is OK